# What is initial size of ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

In Source code of [ArrayList SDK 6](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java/?v=source)

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this(10);
}
```

Where as in [ArrayList.java of SDK 8:](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java/?v=source)

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Where DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for default sized empty instances. We
 * distinguish this from EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA to know how much to inflate when
 * first element is added.
 */
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

Which means ArrayList Default size now is zero but comment says it is still 10.

```
    /**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Please clear confusion?

Comment: thanks @Tunaki.... Original question cleared my doubt